# sudo apt-get update error to fix grub menu

Tags: 13.10

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my PC as dual-boot with Windows 8. However the grub menu doesn't apper, and to fix that I'm supposed to run the `sudo apt-get update` command which is giving error. I'm a newbie to the world of linux, so please help me out here.

Error:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `apt-get update grub`?

Comment: No, just sudo apt-get update. Should I use sudo apt-get update grub?

Comment: No. That's not the proper way to update GRUB. Updating GRUB isn't an action that's controlled by APT. You have to run `sudo update-grub` for that.

Comment: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.

Comment: ^Thats the error I get when I type sudo update-grub.

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings mean that some cdroms are selected as repositories and when you ran `apt-get update`, they were not mounted, so it could not find them.

There is an option in your **System settings > Software & Updates** where you can (un)check whether you want to have your installation media as repository or not. I would advise you tu uncheck it. In my case, it's the option at the bottom of the window, but it might look different in other versions and languages.

[image: Screenshot (German) of the Software&Updates window]

You could also manually edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and convert the lines starting with `cdrom` to comments (writing an `#` before them), that should do the same trick.

But except that you should always keep your system up to date (with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or any other package manager), this has nothing to do with GRUB. The command to create a fresh grub.conf and update the OS list is `sudo update-grub`.

If you want to run `boot-repair` you have to add its PPA first and install it. This is achieved by the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Explanation:

1. adds the PPA to the repository list. `apt-get` can't find it otherwise.
2. updates the index of available software from your repos
3. this command actually installs `boot-repair`
4. now it's time to launch it!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the unchecking of "installation media being a repository" part, I can't find the option in Software & Updates.

Comment: Would a German screenshot help you?

Comment: Sure, something is better than nothing.

Comment: Also, my /etc/apt/sources.list has the following data:

#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 _Qiana_ - Release amd64 20140623]/ trusty contrib main non-free

Comment: I added a screenshot. The line you quoted is already commented out, so it would not get processed. There must be another one...

Comment: No, thats the only line there.

Comment: I saw the screenshot and what I understand is that I have to uncheck the last checkbox from the bottom. Is that right?

Comment: Okay, so I unchecked it and sudo apt-get update worked without errors. But then to repair grub menu, the command I have to use is sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair which is giving error.
error: E: Unable to locate package boot-repair

Comment: You probably forgot to add the PPA as boot-repair is not located in the standard repositories. If not, maybe you forgot to update the index files... I added a paragraph to my answer.